# Can't find "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean" spring + quartz

Tags: spring, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I have in my build path both quartz 1.8.3.jar and Spring 3.0.6 jars, but the package that appears in all tutorials for spring + quartz scheduling isn't available. Where i can find it?

```
   "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it seems to be in spring-context-support : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean

Answer (score 1):

**Quartz** scheduling files are available in `Spring context support 4.3.6 jar`. There is a change in the classes. Few classes have been become deprecated.
The deprecated classes in spring context support are: **JobDetailBean** and **CronTriggerBean**.
 Replace `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean` in your current spring / program file to `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean`.